# Are the train gate sample codes in uppaal incorrect?

Tags: uppaal

Even though I use the train gate example in Uppaal and the code found on the internet exactly, I am getting syntax and undefined errors.  Is there anyone who can share all the code of this example with me?

I tried the code at https://github.com/tiagochst/DPTCS/blob/master/inf342/lab5/uppaal-4.0.11/demo/train-gate.xml and  https://youtu.be/IMHOaQyHqck?si=cxjCN4H21bK8b6jm but I am getting the errors I mentioned and I cannot fix them.

I think the reason is my lack of knowledge but I really need help. I don't know how it can be done without a drawing, but I really need it.

**Project Declarations:**

```
const int N = 6;
typedeft int [0,N-1] id_t;
chan appr,stop,go,leave;
urgent chan go;
```

**Gate Declarations:**

```
id_t list [N+1];
int[0,N] len;

void enqueue(id_t element)
{
    list[len++] = element;
}

void dequeue()
{
    int i = 0;
    len -=1;
    while(i < len)
    {
        list[i] = list[i+1];
        i++;
    }
    list[i]=0;
}
id_t front()
{
return list [0];
}

id_t tail () 
{
return list [ len − 1];
}
```

**Train Declarations:**

```
clock x;
```

**System Declarations:**

```
Process = Template();
Train1:=Train(e1,1);
Train2:=Train(e1,2);
Train3:=Train(e1,3);
Train4:=Train(e1,4);

system Process;
Train1,Train2,Train3,Train4,Gate,Queue
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the error messages you are facing

Comment: Is there anyone who can help? I'm running out of time.

Comment: What Uppaal version are you trying? Can you add a screenshot of the errors?

Comment: The latest Uppaal 5 also contains such train-gate example which works for sure. Currently I don't have the means to test this exact file.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded 5 and accessed the codes from the examples. I have another question, when I write bus instead of train here or go! walk instead! When I write and change the code, I still get syntax errors. What I really want to achieve is to organize an aircraft tower connection. If I write exactly what I want on this subject, is there anyone who can help me with the codes?